# I want to remove broken files from an USB-Stick

Tags: partitioning, usb, trash

I tried setting up a backup on my USB-Stick but at some point it got randomly unmounted and now I have a folder with broken files. I also can't use the trash on the stick anymore because it says that the trash is full and when I try to remove them they just reappear.
Then I tried to use GParted and KDE Partition Manager to format it, I tried the Repair tool on windows partition and tried to overwrite it all with zeros using dd. When I used the command `sudo wipe -rfi backup` it promted that this were a Read-only filesystem which it isn't I can write in my functioning files.
This is the output I got from `ll` in the broken directory:

> d?????????  ? ?      ?           ?            ?  Scɲeenshots/ 
> d?????????  ? ?      ?           ?            ?  ubuntu/ 
> d?????????  ? ?      ?           ?            ? 'ၗhatsApp Images'/ 
> d?????????  ? ?      ?           ?            ?  聘i聣ѴuɲesĀ/

I use Ventoy on this Stick which now doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the USB  stick is malfunctioning. Try  using another one.